# Is there a C++11 syntax file for vim?

Tags: c++, vim, c++11

In particular, the display of initialization lists is really bad:

```
vector<int> v({1,2,3});
```

will highlight the curly braces in red (denoting an error).

Comment: (denoting and error).  [english stack exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6632/4425).

Comment: He's right (but was it necessary?) **.**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is now a C++11 script from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3797, which no longer mark the braces inside parenthesis as error.

Comment: Here's the version of that script on github: https://github.com/vim-scripts/Cpp11-Syntax-Support

Answer (score 36):

As an alternative, you can use

```
let c_no_curly_error=1
```

in your `.vimrc` file so that vim doesn't tag `{}` as error in `()`.

Answer (score 25):

If you use [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic), add this to your **.vimrc** (or .vimrc.local).

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11'
```

Syntastic shows errors for code written in multiple languages.  Each language has a "checker" which is a wrapper to execute an external program.  The external program for the c++ checker is g++.  The c++ checker can pass compiler options to g++ and can be configured.

https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C--:---gcc

If you want to use clang++, you can use these options

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'clang++'
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
```

Comment: Please use the actual clang versioning scheme to denote clang versions, not what apple does with it.

Comment: Pretty sure the question is not about linters or semantic checkers or compilers failing, it is about Vim's native syntax grammar not accepting initializer lists inside parens.

Answer (score 9):

use uniform initialization instead of the old () constructor

vector v {1,2,3};

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is a work in progress for that, see [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_dev@googlegroups.com/msg07955.html) at the vim_dev mail list.

Answer (score 4):

An improved patch for C++11 support has been sent to the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vim_dev/ug_wmWQqyGU

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you know if any distros picked it up? Or isn't it in upstream Vim yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure this in a local syntastic config file.

Drop a `.syntastic_cpp_config` file in your project root and give it the compiler arguments one per line (I also have include paths for the Loki library as an example):

```
-std=c++11
-Ilib/loki/include
-Ilib/loki_book/include
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you use YouCompleteMe,you can change '.ycm_extra_conf.py'.like this:(file path~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py) ;

only change flags

```
flags = [
'-std=c++11',
'-O0',  
'-Werror', 
'-Weverything', 
'-Wno-documentation', 
'-Wno-deprecated-declarations', 
'-Wno-disabled-macro-expansion', 
'-Wno-float-equal', 
'-Wno-c++98-compat', 
'-Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic', 
'-Wno-global-constructors', 
'-Wno-exit-time-destructors', 
'-Wno-missing-prototypes', 
'-Wno-padded', 
'-Wno-old-style-cast',
'-Wno-weak-vtables',
'-x', 
'c++', 
'-I', 
'.', 
'-isystem', 
'/usr/include/',
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I have searched the other proposals about C++11 syntax file of VIM and they are old and not maintained. Anyway, recent distributions of Vim have good syntax files already. Sometimes they are updated though and official source of syntax files is here: https://github.com/vim-jp/vim-cpp