# Is nullptr not a special keyword and an object of std::nullptr_t?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, nullptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282295/500104)

I first thought it's a keyword. My present gcc doesn't highlight `nullptr` in a different shade. To verify that, I wrote following:

```
void *&p = nullptr;
```

So I got some clue from the error that:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘void*&’
>   from an rvalue of type ‘std::nullptr_t’

If `nullptr` is an object then is it really a pointer equivalent of simple `0`? In other word, suppose I write:

```
#define NULL nullptr
```

Is the above statement doesn't alter anything in my code ? Also, it would be interesting to know other use cases for `std::nullptr_t` type as such.

Comment: `gcc doesn't highlight` ==> `VIM editor doesn't highlight in gcc` :)

Comment: Your gcc isn't going to "highlight" `nullptr`. gcc is a compiler; the only presentation from the compiler are the error and warnings that result from compilation; hopefully, there are none. It is your editor is that is going to highlight nullptr. It shouldn't be all that surprising your editor isn't up to speed with the new standard because the new standard doesn't really exist yet, at least not officially. That's why it is still called C++0x rather than C++11.

Comment: See [What exactly is nullptr in C++0x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr-in-c0x/1282345#1282345). Some of your questions are answered there.

Comment: For vim C++0x syntax see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977174/is-there-a-c0x-syntax-file-for-vim

Comment: @eran: I think with 3k+ rep you should already be able to vote for closing as an exact duplicate (which will in turn add a comment similar to the one you added). Thanks for pointing out the duplicate anyway!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a keyword, the standard draft says (*lex.nullptr*):

> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.

the `nullptr` is not yet a pointer, but it can be converted to a pointer type. This forbids your above assignment, which is an assignment to an unrelated reference type, in which case no conversion is possible (consider `int& a = 1.f;`!).

Doing `#define NULL nullptr` shouldn't alter the behaviour unless you did use `NULL` in a context such as `int i = 4; if(NULL == i) {}`, which won't work with `nullptr` because `nullptr` is can't be treated as an integer literal.

I don't think there are many other use-cases for `std::nullptr_t`, it's just a sentinel because `nullptr` needs a type.

Comment: +1, although "shouldn't alter the behaviour unless ..." - in other words, it does break (some) things. `NULL` is guaranteed to have some integer type, `nullptr` isn't.

Comment: There is a small use for `nullptr_t`. If you have several overloads taking different pointer types, then the `nullptr`-to-pointer cast will be ambiguous. You can use a `nullptr_t` overload to disambiguate the call.

Answer (score 6):

`nullptr` is a keyword that represents null pointer constant. It is of type `nullptr_t`, which is implicitly convertible and comparable to any pointer type or pointer-to-member type.

Read these,

- [Null pointer constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Null_pointer_constant) (wiki)
- [nullptr -- a null pointer literal](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#nullptr) (Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ)

Answer (score 4):

`nullptr` is indeed a keyword and the standard demands a type `std::nullptr_t` to be equivalent to `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;` to enable overloading based on `nullptr`.

Answer (score 4):

`nullptr` is not an object just like `0` is not an integer object. The former is a prvalue (i.e. a kind of expression) of type `std::nullptr_t` and the latter is an integer literal (also a kind of expression and also a prvalue) of type `int`.

It is possible to initialize an object with such expressions:

```
void* p = nullptr;
int i = 0;
```

It is not possible to initialize an lvalue reference with such expressions because they are prvalues; an lvalue reference can only be initialized from an lvalue.

```
void*& p = nullptr; // Invalid
int& i = 0; // Invalid
```

Answer (score 3):

`nullptr` will be a keyword in next C++ standard, now called C++0x.

It is needed to disambiguate between `f(int)` and `f(T*)`, so it's not simply 0, but of `nullptr_t`.

I didn't know gcc can highlight code ;-)

Comment: Good catch for gcc highlight. It was a mistake.