# reference and literals in C++

Tags: c++, rvalue

I know that "literals" (c strings, int or whatever) are stored somewhere (in a read only data section apparently .rodata) maybe this is not accurate...

I want to understand why this code causes a runtime error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int& foo()
{
    return 2;
}
const char* bar()
{
    return "Hello !";
}

int main() {

    cout << foo() << endl; // crash

    cout << bar() << endl; // OK

    return 0;
}
```

foo returns a const reference on a literal (2) why does this cause a crash ? is the integer 2 stored in the stack of foo() ?

See also : [Why are string literals l-value while all other literals are r-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value)

Comment: Integer literals are usually stored in the code as instructions like `MOV eax, 0xdeadf00d`, and their only active lifetime is in a register.

Comment: `return 2` will create a temp variable, which will be free after `return`. `return "hello"` will return the address of literal("hello")

Comment: @Thomas but 2 isn't a literal ? it's like having int tmp = 2; return tmp; ????

Comment: @Aminos  when we `int tmp = 2`, it means: give me a variable, whose value is 2. when we ` const char * p = "hello"`, it means: give a variable, whose value is the address of "hello". So "hello" is always there even we free `p`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't you take the address of nullptr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189709/why-cant-you-take-the-address-of-nullptr)

Comment: `tmp` is a variable (instead of literal), which contains a copy of `2`. `p` is a variable, which contains a copy of the address of "hello".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see why this is confusing so I will try to break it down.

**First case:**

```
const int& foo()
{
    return 2;
}
```

The return statement makes a *temporary object* which is a **copy** of the literal `2`. So its address is either *non-extant* or different from the location of the literal `2` (assuming literal `2` has a location - not guaranteed).

It is that temporary whose reference is returned.

**Second case:**

```
const char* bar()
{
    return "Hello !";
}
```

The return statement makes a *temporary object* which is a **copy** of a **pointer** to the *address* of the *first element* of the literal char array. That *pointer* contains the actual address of the literal array and that address is returned *by copy* to the caller.

So to sum up. The second one works because the return statement takes a copy of the literal's *address* and not a copy of the literal itself. It doesn't matter that the storage for the *address* is temporary because the *address* still points to the correct place after the temporary holding its value collapses.

Comment: the copy of "2" exists in which namespace ? foo, main or it ceases to exist after return 2; (the semicolon)

Comment: @Aminos namespaces don't really apply to temporaries. It may exist only in a `CPU` register. It's up to the compiler where it stores it. This is why it is illegal to take the address of a temporary. It ceases to exist immediately after the function hands the "return value" back to the caller. In this case the "return value" is actually a reference.

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed very confusing, and in order to understand what's happening, one has to dive very deep in the language specification.

But before we do this, let me remind you that compiler warnings are your friends. With a sufficient level of warnings, you should see following when compiling your example:

> In function 'const int& foo()': 3 : warning: returning reference to
>   temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr] return 2; ^

Now, what is happening in your first example? One can not really take an address of the integral literal, since they do not really exist as objects. However, one is allowed to bind constant references to literals. How is it possible, when everybody knows that references are akin to pointers? The reason is that when you bind a const reference to the literal, you do not really bind it to the literal. Instead, compiler creates a temporary variable, and binds your reference to it. And that variable is an object, albeit short-lived one. Once you function returns, the temporary object is destroyed, and you end up with dangling reference -> crash.

In the second example, `"hello"` is a literal, but you are not returning the literal - you are returning a pointer to the string. And a pointer remains valid, because the string it points to remains valid.

Comment: the copy of "2" exists in which namespace ? foo, main or it ceases to exist after return 2; (the semicolon) ?