# vim and c++11 lambda: auto indentation

Tags: vim, c++11

Using vim with c++11 lambda functions is actually poor. Indentation is not working and a lot of brackets are marked as erroneous.

As I know the indent and syntax highlighting for c and c++ is programmed internally and not via a c[...].vim file. Is there any chance to set up vim for c++11, especially for source code with lambda functions? Maybe someone can give a hint how and where to add lambda parsing in the internal vim syntax checking?

EDIT: (example code as requested from comments)

The code should look like the following example but is formatted to a single column.

```
  MyLoop( [](int a, int b){
        {       
            ::i++;
            for (;;)
            {   
                SomeFunc();
            }   
            cout << "Result: " << a*b<<endl;
        }       
    });
```

Update for vim 7.4:
Now vim did not longer handle a lambda expression as an error, but it still did NOT do any indentation in the lambda expression and so it is still not usable for c++ anymore :-(

BTW: Has anyone a good auto formatting tool which can be added to vim environment, so that pressing a key externally do the formatting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977174/is-there-a-c0x-syntax-file-for-vim

Comment: Could you add an example of how it is indenting and how you want it to indent?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Vim 7.4 now has an `jN` cinoption for "Indent Java anonymous classes correctly." (`:help java-cinoptions`) This improves indenting behavior for C++11's lambdas.

With these options (put in your ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim):

```
setlocal cindent cino=j1,(0,ws,Ws
```

And if I move your for loop's opening brace to the same line (otherwise it's crazy) then vim indents your code like this:

```
MyLoop( [](int a, int b){
    {       
        ::i++;
        for (;;) {   
            SomeFunc();
        }   
        cout << "Result: " << a*b<<endl;
    }       
});
```

It doesn't give the hanging indent that you want either. If you move the initial opening brace it its own line, then you get your desired hanging indent.

For all the options, see `:help cinoptions-values`.

---

If you want at smarter indenting program, [this user recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20312316/79125) `set equalprg=clang-format` to use [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) so `=ip` will indent the current paragraph. This won't make vim correctly indent as you type (you need to setup indentexpr for that and that's quite complicated).

There's also [a vim plugin](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format) that seems to do the same as setting equalprg, but with more code. Not sure if it's any better. It's supposed to be an alternative to [clang-format.py](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#vim-integration) (from Cyprian Guerra's answer).

Comment: Nice. If you don't want to create ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim file, you can also add to .vimrc following line:
`autocmd BufEnter *.cpp :setlocal cindent cino=j1,(0,ws,Ws`

Comment: I added `setlocal cindent cino=j1,(0,ws,Ws` to my `~/.vimrc` and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider: Because you're using `setlocal` without an ftplugin or autocmd, that will only apply to the first file you edit. Use `set` to make it the default for all files (which still might be overwritten by ftplugins -- [see here for help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585591/79125)).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
:let c_no_curly_error = 1
```

You can put that into your vimrc for example.

As for your assumption, it is wrong. There is a `c.vim` syntax file (in vim runtime). You can see a reference in `:help c.vim` and the implementation by looking it up in your vim runtime paths (`:echo &rtp`).

Comment: This solution remove marks from wrong placed braces, which is not what I prefer. Indentation is still wrong.

Comment: While there is a C syntax file, the indenting is done internally and this seemed to be the important issue in the OP's post.

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3797) project by Michael Small.  I haven't tried it yet, but perhaps it's what you're looking for.

Comment: With these new syntax files installed I got no erroneous braces any more, but indentation is still wrong for lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

set smartindent autoindent

Then you type above code in vim,you will get the right indentation.

**BUT**,if you use gg=G or commands that contain "=" to re-indent above code,the indentation is still wrong.

Comment: gg=G is the important part of the feature :-) And also the red marked braces are not very beautiful. OK, as mentioned above I can suppress ALL warnings for wrong braces, but this is also not helpful. I am really wondering why nobody implement the correct indent file for vim. I actually run only external formatters which is really stupid! Is vim outdated or is c++11 not used often? There are now 2 years without a fix for the problem... BTW: Initializer lists are also broken with vim :-(

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is [clang-format.py](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) from LLVM guys or [vim-clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format) from Linda_pp a.k.a. rhysd (thanks idbrii for the latter) - both use `clang` therefore both support all of the C++11 new structures and you can run it as follows:

```
:pyf ~/src/llvm.git/tools/clang/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py
```

or
    :ClangFormat

The latter seems better as it (among other features) allows to follow the "one config file for the same behaviour on every environment" rule, especially when you use a VIM add-on manager (e.g. VAM).

Comment: [vim-clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format) claims to be a superior alternative to [clang-format.py](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#vim-integration). Not sure either are better than equalprg.

Comment: clang-format changes a ton of formatting unrelated to indenting, which isn't always desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this for a few days, looks like toggling on smartindent with cindent enabled helped me out with it lambda indentation in C++11.

In your ~/.vimrc

```
set cindent
set smartindent
```

Hope this helps peeps out.

Comment: I see no change. All indentations inside the lambda expression are still broken. All braces are shifted to a single column. Can you show how the indentation looks with you setup?