# Tuning C++ IDE plugin for Vim

Tags: c++, vim, c++11

Question is about how to tune [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213) plugin to vim. I want to change behavior of it when I push `\rc`, i.e. I want compile the file. I want compile with g++ with -std:c++0x option. As I understand I should change global variable g:C_CplusCompiler from defaults value "g++" to "-std:c++0x g++".

Update: thanks @holygeek for showing right command to change global variable in vim:
 `:let g:C_CplusCompiler="g++ -std=c++0x"`. However it doesn't not help to compile with `\rc` and right option `-std:c++0x`. Any ideas? I have not found how to do it in manual :(

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a C++0x syntax file for vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2977174/636019), [vim and c++11 lambda: auto indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8062608/636019)

Answer (score 2):

In vim set is used to set a setting. To set a variable use the let command:

```
:let g:C_CplusCompiler="g++ -std:c++0x"
```