# Vim compile file with c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, vim

I have recently been using Vim as my C++ IDE with the wonderful [c.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213).  However I have been stymied by implementing C++11 code.  I initially thought the answer posted to this nearly identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685185/tuning-c-ide-plugin-for-vim) would help.  But as I have tried to reset the compiler global variable in my vimrc:

```
let g:C_CplusCompiler="g++ -std:c++0x"
```

or

```
let g:C_CplusCompiler="g++ -std=c++0x"
```

I keep getting the following error for both scenarios:

```
E518: Unkown option: -std:c++0x
```

This compilation does work find, however, if I simply do it in the command line with:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test
```

Am I somehow missing something in the documentation to have vim compile with `std-c++0x`?

Comment: Neither of your examples use `-std=c++0x`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @0x499602D2, no luck.  After I press `\rr` it just returns: `file 'mypath/test.exe' does not exist or is not executable or object/source older then executable`.  Unsure it you were referring to the initial typo.

Comment: `-std=c++11` try that

Comment: @self, thank you but still same problem with `unknown option: -std=c++11`.

Comment: Yeah I was referring to the typo.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, does YouCompleteMe provide compilation functionality?  I mainly like c.vim because I can compile and run my small programs with one command `\rr`.

Comment: @cdeterman Err, forget what I said. Those two plugins are indeed orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

#### Without any plugin

If your make is gnu-make (and not mingw's one) you just need to set

```
:let $CXXFLAGS='-std=c++0x -Wall +whatever-other-options'
```

and then compile you mono file project with

```
:make %<
```

#### In the shell

If this doesn't work, make sure your compiler support this option. In the shell, try:

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++0x make test
```

or if your really want to compile by hand:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o test test.cpp
```

#### With another plugin

With [BuildToolsWrappers](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/BTW), for mono-file projects still, you'll need to set $CXXFLAGS, and then type either `:Make`, or `<F7>` to compile the current mono-file project. And you can run it with `<CTRL-F5>`. (Both keybindings can be configured).

N.B.: *BTW* plugin also support multi-files projects. Then you'll have to have a Makefile, or equivalent, where the $CXXFLAGS will be set.