# How to find out, in which plugin a Vim setting gets changed?

Tags: vim

Today I had some obscure behavior. I have

```
set autoindent
```

in my vimrc, but for some reason, this gets turned off, whenever i open a PHP file.

I've fixed it now by adding a line like

```
autocmd FileType php set autoindent
```

But I'm still trying to figure out, where this setting is disabled. So is there some way to find out, where in the vim config a setting gets changed?

For reference here's my full `vimrc.local` that I'm using on Ubuntu:

https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/1612035/5fa149468006577d193858bbc8cefcd3a413e017

EDIT:
The problem was caused by a `filetype indent on` that I added some time ago to my config. No idea, why that affects autoindent, though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `:verbose` command will tell you where an option was last changed:

```
:verbose set autoindent?
```

If that alone doesn't help, you can inspect all executed commands, preferably with the output redirected into a logfile:

```
:set verbosefile=vim.log
:20verbose edit foo.php
```

Also note that there are several options controlling indentation, e.g. `'cindent'`, `'smartindent'`, `'indentexpr'`, etc.

<sup>PS: To avoid that the changed option value spills into other buffers, it's recommended to use `:setlocal` instead.</sup>

Comment: Hmm. I've tried, but if i type that in the console it just displays "autoindent". Am I missing something?

Comment: Other indent settings may be to blame. If all fails, you have to inspect every executed command; I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. FYI The problem was caused by a `filetype indent on` that i added recently.

Comment: I'm glad that you've figured it out. Yeah, that change is supposed to affect indent settings, isn't it :-)

Comment: Well, it's not documented, that it would :). Side note: Finding good indentation settings for any other language but C seems to be a real pain in Vim. All the available options can become very confusing (as my question shows). And none of the different PHP configurations I tried was without flaws. So probably have to stick with `autoindent`. If you have some pointers here, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl "It isn't documented" is a phrase we're used to say often, but in the case of Vim it almost never applies ;) Copious documentation at `:h :filetype-indent-on`. By the way, the culprit is the bundled PHP indent script, which contains an explicit `setlocal noautoindent`.

Comment: @glts I've read that before. Still can't see where it says "Turning filetype indenting on disables autoindet.". `autoindent` is only mentioned here: "*Reset 'autoindent', 'cindent', 'smartindent' and/or
'indentexpr' to disable indenting in an opened file.*". TBH I don't get, what this sentence tries to tell me :P.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl It doesn't say "Turning filetype indenting on disables autoindent" because it isn't true! What `:filetype indent on` does is enable Vim's own per-filetype indent scripts. What an indent script does is the responsibility of the script maintainer. You can see the PHP indent script by doing `:e $VIMRUNTIME/indent/php.vim`: in *there* you will find the setting `noautoindent`. If that is wise or not I can't say. Best,

Answer (score 0):

Isnt that line the problem?

```
autocmd FileType php set cindent|set cinkeys-=0#
```