# Ansi C support in Vim

Tags: c++, c, vim

I've just start learning vim (and i want to write some C code in it). So I installed cvim. But i don't like it. U have write really fast (for one if() .. else u have to pres \ and in 1 second "sif"). Also the C style is K&R - i really hate. SO if there are any plugin for auto competition for vim ?

Comment: what is your platform ?

Comment: Im using  vim by cygWin. Only to lern it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm under Linux and I use vim in conjunction with:

- [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) to get the autocomplete feature
- I have customized the `ftplugin` under `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim` a little bit like so

> ```
> set equalprg=clang-format
> nmap <F9> gg=G``a     
> imap <F9> <ESC>gg=G``a 
> set autoindent     
> set cindent
> ```

`clang-format` is part of the clang compiler suite, I don't have any idea if this works under CygWin but `equalprg` is just a proxy to any program that is capable to format a source file, for example [`astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) is a quite popular alternative.

With this setup if you press `F9` in vim `clang-format` will be called to format your code.

And that's all I need personally to have a functional vim.

If your computer can handle it, I suggest to just use a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows, you may want to use [gVim](http://gvim.en.softonic.com/).
gVim doesn't have code completion. To enable K&R style, you must type :set cindent, and disable it by :set nocindent.

Comment: Well i said that i WANT to have code completion and i DON'T like K&R style

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question.