# Vim : Override equalprg with a command with argument

Tags: c++, c, vim, clang-format

I would like to override the = vim operator with clang-format using my own style sheet for C/C++ files:
This idea is to make a `clang-format -i -style=~/.my_own_clang_format_config` inside vim.

I tried the following commands without success:
(from [Ansi C support in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312198/ansi-c-support-in-vim/20312316#20312316)) :`set equalprg=clang-format` --> Does not take any indentation

`set equalprg="clang-format -style='~/.my_own_clang_format_config'"` --> a echom &equalprg returns an empty string

`set equalprg='clang-format -i -style=~/.my_own_clang_format_config'` --> Unknown option: -i

I tried also to add some `shellescape` after the = but it is not interpreted... Any idea?

[EDIT] : `-style='.my_own_clang_format_config'` is not a valid option for clang-format. I had to use the following option :
`clang-format -style='file'` and add my custom .clang_format in my folder (or the root folder of my project) to make it work without vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to escape the whitespaces since that interferes from calling the command within the vim command line mode.

```
set equalprg=clang-format\ -i\ -style='~/.my_own_clang_format_config'
```

Edit: The whitespace is used to determine multiple arguments to the command being called, in this case `:set`. Escaping them enables VIM to interpret the latter to be a single coherent statement assigning the vim option `equalprg`.

Comment: thanks for the tips ! Please note also that I did another mistake: this is not the expected syntax to declare a custom clang_format file :
`clang-format -style` option waits for a keyword instead of a custom string. Here I had to use `-style='file'` and add my .clang_format file on the root of my project.