# Vim indent C++11 lambdas which have opening brace on new line

Tags: c++, vim, lambda, indentation

So I would like to indent the following code as is shown below:

```
foo.bar([] ()
{
    // something
});
```

I currently have the following: `cinoptions=j1,(4`, which results in:

```
foo.bar([] ()
    {
        // something
    });
```

Notice the 4 spaces indentation for the whole lambda (which I don't want). Does anyone have ideas how I can make the above work, while still indenting the following code:

```
fooish(bar1, bar2,
    bar3);
```

i.e I want that regular parameters, when on a new line, are idented by 4 spaces, but not lambdas?

EDIT: This question is different from [vim and c++11 lambda: auto indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062608/vim-and-c11-lambda-auto-indentation) . I already know and am using the `-j1` option, but I want to know if there is some way to control the identation of the whole lambda block, not just inside it.

Comment: @Harish edited the post to explain why this isn't a duplicate. I am asking about achieving specific identation for lambdas, which is different from the other question.

Comment: Okay, my bad then, removing the comment.