# VI to recognize C++11 keywords

Tags: c++, c++11, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a C++11 syntax file for vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977174/is-there-a-c11-syntax-file-for-vim)

How can i update my `VI` settings for it to recognize (and highlight appropriately) new keywords that came about with the new standard.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone already wrote some syntax files for C++11: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3797. It even makes initializer lists and lambdas work fine without vim thinking the curlies are errors.

I remember I had to manually add some missing keywords to it, but that's not terribly complicated (just grep the file for the other keywords and add new ones). My current setup is up on [GitHub](https://github.com/rmartinho/vim-cpp11). If you are using vundle you can install it with `Bundle 'rmartinho/vim-cpp11'`.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, can you upload your modified files to github or somewhere else so we can grab your changes?

Comment: @Frank late, I know, but I have put it up now :|