# Vim syntax high-lighting for C++11 that does not mess up other highlighting. E.g., class/namespace scoping

Tags: c++, vim, plugins, syntax, c++11

I am aware of this script: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3797. It has been suggested a few times, and other questions regarding C++11 syntax for Vim have been shut down due to duplicating this question: [Is there a C++11 syntax file for vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977174/is-there-a-c11-syntax-file-for-vim).

Unfortunately, the suggested script results in scoping constructs (e.g. "namespace::member()") not being highlighted anymore, *and* functions and class names are no longer highlighted.

Does anyone have a better C++11 plugin for Vim available now? Ideally, all the features of the regular C++ plugin being retained, new keywords/reserved words marked (e.g. nullptr), lambda expressions/universal initialization syntax not flagged as errors. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following? I use this one and like it

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4617