# Vim syntax highlighting error C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vim

So vim is highlighting the following C++ syntax as red for me. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

```
some_hash_table[{std::string(name), age}];
```

I have specialized std::hash<> to accept a custom Pair value, which has its own std::pair constructor to make the above legal.

NOTE : Adding in the C++11 vimrc file did not help in this case.

Comment: Put `let c_no_curly_error=1` in your .vimrc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a C++11 syntax file for vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977174/is-there-a-c11-syntax-file-for-vim)

Comment: What does that do exactly? Thanks

Comment: It should (hopefully) fix your problem :)

Comment: @Mauris No I have that syntax file and this is one case where the file's syntax doesn't prevent the red highlighting

Comment: It did fix the problem. Thanks! But I was wondering what exactly it does. I just don't want the syntax highlighting to disappear completely. Just in this case