# Unwanted highlighting on braces inside brackets in Vim when using c++

Tags: c++, vim, highlight

My vim editor highlights the pattern [{}] when I'm writing c++ code.
[image: screenshot]

It highlights the braces in the same way it would highlight search matches, however the command `:nohl` doesn't yield anything.
Any ideas on how to turn this off?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600155/vim-syntax-highlighting-error-c tl;dr put `let c_no_curly_error=1` in your .vimrc

Comment: Also please do not use bits/stdc++.h, search this site to find out why.

Comment: Huh, I never found that question when googling. I use bits/stdc++ for competitive programming. Thanks